# Verificação de erro fora de laço de repetição

Tags: vb.net

Preciso verificar se o conteúdo de um arquivo está em ordem alfabética, mas quero que exiba apenas uma mensagem com a verificação de erro. Com o código que estou usando, ele exibe os erros de acordo com a quantidade de itens.

```
Dim local_arquivo As String
Dim c As Char
Dim split As String()
Dim ordemalf As String

DataGridTodos.Rows.Clear()
local_arquivo = TextBox.Text
Dim leitura As New System.IO.StreamReader(local_arquivo, System.Text.Encoding.Default)
c = ";"
While leitura.Peek() <> -1
    split = leitura.ReadLine().Split(c)
    ordemalf = split(1)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To split(1).Length - 1
        If ordemalf(0) > "A" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Arquivo incorreto!", "VESCPF", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Else
            DataGridTodos.Rows.Add(split)
        End If
    Next
End While
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 2):

Se você deseja exibir uma mensagem de erro para cada linha que não possui a ordem necessária você pode utilizar boolean.

```
Dim local_arquivo As String
Dim c As Char
Dim split As String()
Dim ordemalf As String

DataGridTodos.Rows.Clear()
local_arquivo = TextBox.Text
Dim leitura As New System.IO.StreamReader(local_arquivo, System.Text.Encoding.Default)
c = ";"
While leitura.Peek() <> -1
    Dim error As Boolean
    split = leitura.ReadLine().Split(c)
    ordemalf = split(1)
    error = False
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To split(1).Length - 1
        If ordemalf(0) > "A" Then
            error = True
            Exit For
        Else
            DataGridTodos.Rows.Add(split)
        End If
    Next

    If error = True
        MessageBox.Show("Arquivo incorreto!", "VESCPF", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        ' Para o loop na primeira ocorrência
        Exit While
End While
```

Dessa forma o erro será exibido a cada linha incorreta.

O código `Exit For` é utilizado para sair do Loop quando ele achar o erro.

O código `Exit While` é utilizado para parar o Loop na primeira ocorrência.

Comment: E pra parar o loop na primeira ocorrência?

Comment: Editei a resposta!